# Why am I getting a compile error for my URLDownloadToFile function declaration in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run a macro on my 64-bit Excel that downloads images from a list of URLs in an excel spreadsheet. But When I try to run the code below, excel highlights the 8 lines of code at the top, starting with Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile, and gives me this error message: "Compile Error: Only comments may appear after End Sub, End Function, or End Property". Why is that?

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
      Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
        ByVal pCaller As LongPtr, _
        ByVal szURL As String, _
        ByVal szFileName As String, _
        ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
        ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr _
      ) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function DeleteUrlCacheEntry Lib "Wininet.dll" _
      Alias "DeleteUrlCacheEntryA" ( _
        ByVal lpszUrlName As String _
      ) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
      Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
        ByVal pCaller As Long, _
        ByVal szURL As String, _
        ByVal szFileName As String, _
        ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
        ByVal lpfnCB As Long _
      ) As Long
    Private Declare Function DeleteUrlCacheEntry Lib "Wininet.dll" _
      Alias "DeleteUrlCacheEntryA" ( _
        ByVal lpszUrlName As String _
      ) As Long
#End If

Public Const ERROR_SUCCESS As Long = 0
Public Const BINDF_GETNEWESTVERSION As Long = &H10
Public Const INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD As Long = &H80000000
Public Const folderName As String = "c:\temp\"

Sub downloadImages()
    Dim i As Long, ret As Long, sWAN As String, sLAN As String
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For i = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            sLAN = folderName & .Cells(i, 1).Value & ".jpg"
            sWAN = .Cells(i, 2).Value

            ret = URLDownloadToFile(0&, sWAN, sLAN, BINDF_GETNEWESTVERSION, 0&)
            
            If ret = 0 Then
                .Cells(i, 3) = "File successfully downloaded"
            Else
                .Cells(i, 3) = "Unable to download the file"
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Code compiles for me. Error message says that you have an `End Sub, End Function ..` before the declarations of  `URLDownloadToFile ` in your original file.

Comment: Thank you! @storax! You're right, there was a Sub that existed before my URLDownloadToFile declaration and that was causing the problem.